# Laravel | PHP | How to use file_get_contents?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to learn and to understand how can i use data, sent from an external server into my laravel project.

So i made this route :

```
Route::get('/receive','MyController@Receive');
```

And in Controller i did that :

```
 public function Receive(Request $request){
     $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
     $json_dat = json_decode($data, true);
     echo $json_dat;
 }
```

Using POSTMAN, i sent i POST request to `http://my_domain/receive

With Body > Row > JSON APP 
And a simple table like that :
`

```
[{
    "type_3": "Hero",
 }]
```

When executing the URL in Postman, nothing happens in echo `$json_dat`

What I'm expecting is : Json data with type_3 : Hero

Thank you in advance

[image: Postman action]

Comment: What *does* happen?

Comment: Thank you for ur interest. The response is blank. Nothing is printed

Comment: your using a `::get()` route, when it should be `::post()`, also, it's better to use `$_POST` to get the info received.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you're expecting a GET request rather than POST.

change

```
Route::get('/receive','MyController@Receive');
```

to

```
Route::post('/receive','MyController@Receive');
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. When i change the route GET to POST . I'm getting error : 
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: You say "Using POSTMAN, i sent i POST request" but you're not sending a POST if Laravel's responding with that error.

Comment: @ceejayoz i update post for you. I added an image of my postman action. Please correct me if that wrong

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Curtis, the first thing you need to do is to change the route from `get` to `post`.

Next, you want to send valid json request body with proper `Content-Type`:`application/json` header:

```
{  
   "type_3":"Hero"
}
```

In the controller itself, you do not need to manually retrieve input as Laravel is smart enough to be able to capture and parse json for you.

You can access your values using the request object `$request->input('type_3')` or `$request->all()` or many more functions for this purpose such as `json()`, `post()` etc.

Hope you can figure out based on this.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting Error : The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. ??

Comment: @yassinej yes, because you are sending POST request from Postman, but expecting GET request in your Laravel routes. All you need to do is change `Route::get` to `Route::post`

Answer (score 0):

Use post instead get 
in router

```
Route::post('/receive','MyController@Receive');
```

in controller

```
public function Receive(Request $request){


    $request->json('type_3'); // hero  get from json

    $request->input('type_3'); // get from input



   return $request->all(); //return all input,request or json and vs vs
 }
```

Comment: Thank you , but i'm getting : The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.